# What technology to use to build Apple Watch's Siri Waveform

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, core-graphics, fft

I'm building music player for iOS.
I want to have a visualizer, that is very similar to waveform of [Siri on Apple Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3m7t.png).

I've found open source project on [Github](https://github.com/AustinChou/YZWaveformView) that looks promising. It uses Core Graphics for drawing and is quite simple to understand. But it uses ~50% of CPU on iPhone 6 and with high amplitudes it can't achieve 60 fps. 
Is there any way to achieve this effect using UIKit or SpriteKit with improved performance (notice blending effect - it's very important)? Also, author of this project says something about FFT (in todos). I spent almost a day to understand FFT, but I'm still not sure how it can help in this case to achieve the effect (or maybe to become more performant).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SiriWaveView](https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCSiriWaveformView). Download from github.

Then you can make instance of it like,

```
 siriWaveView = [[SCSiriWaveformView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - 160 + 120, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, 80)]; //you can set your desired frame
    siriWaveView.backgroundColor = appGrayColor;
```

then you can set properties like,

```
    [siriWaveView setWaveColor:myColor]; //desired color
    [siriWaveView setPrimaryWaveLineWidth:3.0f];
    [siriWaveView setSecondaryWaveLineWidth:1.0];
```

Implement this methods,

```
  - (void)updateMeters
{  
if (audioPlayer.playing) {


    CGFloat normalizedValue;
    [audioPlayer updateMeters];
    normalizedValue = [self _normalizedPowerLevelFromDecibels:[audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0]];
    [siriWaveView updateWithLevel:normalizedValue];
    //  NSLog(@"Update meter called");

}


 }

 - (CGFloat)_normalizedPowerLevelFromDecibels:(CGFloat)decibels
{
if (decibels < -60.0f || decibels == 0.0f) {
    return 0.0f;
}

return powf((powf(10.0f, 0.05f * decibels) - powf(10.0f, 0.05f * -60.0f)) * (1.0f / (1.0f - powf(10.0f, 0.05f * -60.0f))), 1.0f / 2.0f);
}
```

when play audio or music call like,

```
   displaylink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateMeters)];
    [displaylink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

You can refer demo project from that link for better understanding.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for fast answer. I've already tested most of Siri-like waveforms on Github. [YZWaveformView](https://github.com/AustinChou/YZWaveformView) from post above is based on SiriWaveView. Still I need fill waveforms and blend them to achieve desired effect.